# Google Play Services Framework Location does not give exact location sometimes

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-location

I developed below code and we need exact location of user. However my customer says that it gets location exactly but sometimes they are wrong. What is wrong?
Thank you

```
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest
                .setInterval(LocationUtils.UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        mLocationRequest
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        // Set the interval ceiling to one minute
        mLocationRequest
                .setFastestInterval(LocationUtils.FAST_INTERVAL_CEILING_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(30);
        // Note that location updates are off until the user turns them on
        mUpdatesRequested = true;
        mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's nothing wrong in your code. It's how fused provider works. In my observation it is still better to use it (instead of reading plain GPS) because it tries to combine GPS with triangulated location. You however need to ensure user got GPS on because fused provider does not require it to be enabled.

Comment: Thank you for your concern. However documentation says that  

"Use with a priority constant such as PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY. No other values are accepted.
The priority of the request is a strong hint to the LocationClient for which location sources to use. For example, PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY is more likely to use GPS.."

So it will use GPS regarding to my code.

Comment: They key here is word **PRIORITY**'. It means that ***if*** there's GPS enabled, it will be used over other sources. But this flag does not force user to enable GPS. So if he got that off, you will got crappy traingulated location, that's why you need to enforce in your app GPS to be enabled so your priority will really be giving you any results